# sending a list through UDP

Tags: python, sockets, udp, python-2.x

I'm using socket programming for sending a UDP text message and it's working fine. Here is the code:

**send:**

```
import socket
UDP_IP = "10.0.0.2"
UDP_PORT = 5005
MESSAGE = "Hello"
print "UDP target IP:", UDP_IP
print "UDP target port:", UDP_PORT
print "message:", MESSAGE
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # UDP
sock.sendto(MESSAGE, (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))
```

**recv:**

```
import socket

UDP_IP = "10.0.0.2"
UDP_PORT = 5005
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # UDP
sock.bind((UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))
while True:
  data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024)
  print "received message:", data
```

Now I want to change the message I'm sending to a list. I tried to do this by using `pickle`. Here is the code:

**send:**

```
import socket
import pickle

UDP_IP = "10.0.0.2"
UDP_PORT = 5005
a = []
a.append('H')
a.append('G')
MESSAGE = pickle.dumps(a)
print "UDP target IP:", UDP_IP
print "UDP target port:", UDP_PORT
print "message:", MESSAGE
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # UDP
sock.sendto(MESSAGE, (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))
```

**recv:**

```
import socket
import pickle

UDP_IP = "10.0.0.2"
UDP_PORT = 5005

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # UDP
sock.bind((UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))
while True:
  data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024)
  print "received message:", data
  pickle.loads(data)
  print(data)
```

But I'm not getting the correct form of the list in the receiver side. Here is the output:

```
(1p0
S'H'
p1
aS'G'
p2
a.

(1p0
S'H'
p1
aS'G'
p2
a.
```

what's wrong?

Comment: What are you getting on the receiver side?  (`print(repr(data))`)

Comment: @snakecharmerb I updated my post.

Comment: You're calling `pickle.loads` on fragments of the message.  You need to keep building up the string until you have it all, then call `pickle.loads`.  Of course, you need a way to work out when you have received the full message...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is solved. The code is working fine, there was a problem because I was printing the data itself not the output of `pickle.loads(data)`, So this code is working fine now:

**recv:**

```
import socket
import pickle

UDP_IP = "10.0.0.2"
UDP_PORT = 5005

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # UDP
sock.bind((UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))
while True:
  data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024)
  print "received message:", data
  print(pickle.loads(data))
```

Answer (score 0):

*Sockets* are operating on bytes (binary data).
Encode your string when sending data to socket connection (`str.encode()`) 
and decode byte sequence received from socket with `bytes.decode('utf8')`.

https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sockets.html#socket-howto

Comment: thanks, but why does it work fine when I send a simple string message like "hello"?

Comment: By the way I added the `encode()` and `decode()`, but it didn't solve the problem.